# How can I get my image previews back in explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

For some reason, first all .png images stopped previewing, and now ALL images stopped. It's very frustrating as it's difficult to see what I'm doing. Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open any folder in windows go to extra/organise (Strumenti?), click `"Folder Options"`. Under the `"Files and Folders"` tab, uncheck the box next to `"Always show icons, never thumbnails"`.

Click the OK or apply button.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'organise' menu of any explorer window choose 'folder options' go to the view tab and un-check 'Always show icons, never thumbnails' and apply. Do bear in mind that this will significantly slow some older computers.

Comment: It was an unanswered question when I began to respond.